# Callback domain contains port number in Yahoo oAuth2

Tags: yahoo-oauth

I am getting error when doing OAuth2 for Yahoo in my application:

> **Error**: Uh oh
>   Looks like something went wrong.
>   Please try again later.

I have figure the problem is my redirect_url contains port number (i.e) http://mydomain:3000/auth/yahoo/callback

How should I define the port number in Callback Domain at the time of application creation on https://developer.yahoo.com

Comment: When do you get this error? Is it when it after you logged in or when you try to open the login page on yahoo?

Comment: after login, when yahoo redirected